# Combination of inputs in the snakemake shell script

Tags: python, shell, wildcard, snakemake

I have the below bash script that I would like to convert into a snakefile:

```
mmseqs rbh flye_db megahit_db flye_megahit_rbh --min-seq-id 0.9 mmseq2_tmp --threads 12
mmseqs rbh flye_db metaspades_db flye_metaspades_rbh --min-seq-id 0.9 mmseq2_tmp --threads 12
mmseqs rbh megahit_db metaspades_db megahit_metaspades_rbh --min-seq-id 0.9 mmseq2_tmp --threads 12
```

I've managed to come up with the following, but was wondering if there's a way to use regex or expand to improve the code further:

```
rule mmseq2_compare:
    input:
        mm1=expand(os.path.join(RESULTS_DIR, "annotation/mmseq2/{assembler}_db"), assembler="flye"),
        mm2=expand(os.path.join(RESULTS_DIR, "annotation/mmseq2/{assembler}_db"), assembler="megahit"),
        mm3=expand(os.path.join(RESULTS_DIR, "annotation/mmseq2/{assembler}_db"), assembler="metaspades_hybrid")
    output: 
        mo1=os.path.join(RESULTS_DIR, "annotation/mmseq2/flye_megahit_rbh"),
        mo2=os.path.join(RESULTS_DIR, "annotation/mmseq2/flye_metaspades_hybrid_rbh"),
        mo3=os.path.join(RESULTS_DIR, "annotation/mmseq2/megahit_metaspades_hybrid_rbh")
    log: os.path.join(RESULTS_DIR, "annotation/mmseq2/compare.mmseq2.log")
    conda: "cd-hit.yml"
    shell:
        """
        (date &&\
        mmseqs rbh {input.mm1} {input.mm2} {output.mo1} --min-seq-id 0.9 mmseq2_tmp --threads 12 &&\
        mmseqs rbh {input.mm1} {input.mm3} {output.mo2} --min-seq-id 0.9 mmseq2_tmp --threads 12 &&\
        mmseqs rbh {input.mm2} {input.mm3} {output.mo3} --min-seq-id 0.9 mmseq2_tmp --threads 12 &&\
        date) &> >(tee {log})
        """
```

With the 3 assemblers (flye, megahit and metaspades_hybrid) is there any way to remove the redundancy especially in the 'shell'?

Thank you!

**Dry-run output**

````
Building DAG of jobs...
Job counts:
        count   jobs
        1       all
        1       mmseq_compare
        2

[Thu Mar 26 12:25:14 2020]
rule mmseq_compare:
    input: results/annotation/mmseq2/flye_db, results/annotation/mmseq2/megahit_db
    output: results/annotation/mmseq2/flye_megahit_rbh
    jobid: 1
    wildcards: assembler1=flye, assembler2=megahit

mmseqs rbh results/annotation/mmseq2/flye_db results/annotation/mmseq2/megahit_db results/annotation/mmseq2/flye_megahit_rbh --min-seq-id 0.9 mmseq2_tmp --threads 12

[Thu Mar 26 12:25:14 2020]
localrule all:
    input: results/annotation/mmseq2/flye_megahit_rbh, results/annotation/mmseq2/flye_metaspades_hybrid_rbh, results/annotation/mmseq2/megahit_metaspades_hybrid_rbh
    jobid: 0

Job counts:
        count   jobs
        1       all
        1       mmseq_compare
        2
This was a dry-run (flag -n). The order of jobs does not reflect the order of execution.```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you don't need an `expand` in your input. This is needed if you wish to create a list of filenames that have the same pattern.

Next, as long as you already use Unix-type slash in your paths, you may add the `RESULTS_DIR` into f-strings for readability (but don't forget to double the braces for wildcards).

Finally, there is no need in having a pipeline of scripts separated with &&: that is what Snakemake is designed for.

My version of reworked script:

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand(f"{RESULTS_DIR}/annotation/mmseq2/{{assembler1}}__{{assembler2}}_rbh", zip,
               assembler1=["flye", "flye", "megahit"],
               assembler2=["megahit", "megahit_metaspades_hybrid", "megahit_metaspades_hybrid"])

rule mmseq_compare:
    input:
        f"{RESULTS_DIR}/annotation/mmseq2/{{assembler1}}_db",
        f"{RESULTS_DIR}/annotation/mmseq2/{{assembler2}}_db"
    output: 
        f"{RESULTS_DIR}/annotation/mmseq2/{{assembler1}}__{{assembler2}}_rbh"
    conda:
        "cd-hit.yml"
    shell:
        "mmseqs rbh {input[0]} {input[1]} {output} --min-seq-id 0.9 mmseq2_tmp --threads 12"
```

I've excluded the `date` and logging. My solution has a limitaton that the order of execution of the comparisons is undefined: you need to reconsider the logging strategy in this case.

Comment: Thank you for this. Couple of questions: 1. what does the "f" at the beginning of the line do? 2. When I do a dry-run, it's only building this file - ```mmseqs rbh results/annotation/mmseq2/flye_db results/annotation/mmseq2/megahit_db results/annotation/mmseq2/flye_megahit_rbh --min-seq-id 0.9 mmseq2_tmp --threads 12```. The other combinations, flye_metaspades_hybrid and megahit_metaspades_hybrid are not being printed. Any idea why?

Comment: The f-string allows you to embed simple expressions into strings (that will be substituted with the result of expression evaluation). In this case in the string f"{RESULTS_DIR}/annotation" the {RESULTS_DIR} will be replaces with the actual value of thie veriable. Regarding dry-run: please provide full output of dry-run.

Comment: Thank you.. I've updated the question with the dry-run output.
And sorry, I accidentally added the dry-run output to your answer. Please delete it!

Comment: @SusheelBusi I've updated my answer. An additional underscore solves the issue. This however looks like a bug to me that Snakemake doesn't match possible combination without double underscores. I'll investigate the issue.

Comment: The double underscore probably fixes some ambiguity in the wildcards from unconstrained regex's with underscores.  I'm surprised by the output, I would think it would throw an exception from not finding inputs or similar.  You can use camel case for the assemblers or another separator in the wildcards or filenames (-).

Comment: @TroyComi There is no ambiguity even with a single underscore, but Snakemake finds the only possible wildcards resolution ignoring other ones.

Comment: @Dmitry: I can confirm that the double-underscore works. It's interesting, but that causes a minor problem for downstream process which use this file. A simple rename should take care of that. Nonetheless, thank you very much! If you do figure out why the "__" is needed though, let me know. Thanks again!

Comment: @SusheelBusi If you cannot afford renaming the files you can always use `wildcard_constraints`.

Comment: Thank you. Never used them but will try.